# I have Ubuntu 16.04,how to install Windows,dual boot

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows

This is my current configuration
[image]

Should I make new partition for Windows?I wouldn't like to destroy my current Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 1):

yea preferred to make new partition and that's wont affect your Ubuntu , 
but make sure you don't format the Ubuntu , 
First make new partition before installing Windows (ntfs partition)
second install windows on that free partition.
and you may find when reboot that the device just boot for windows or Ubuntu , it's okay , you have to update your Grub then you will find the both at Grub list.
I did the same but was having windows first.